# Listing service methods in the OSGi service registry

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have OSGi bundles that provide services and require services.

If I have a service that implements an interface and the interface provides a variety of methods, can I have **references to these methods** in the service registry or somewhere so other bundles can find them?

Answer (score 3):

If a service implements an interface then any method on that interface is implemented by that service, by definition in Java. So any other bundle that knows about the service (and thus the interface) is fully aware of these methods.

If you want to advertise to bundles that do **not** know the interface, then you could register properties. However, by definition accessing those methods would require reflection. In general this is not the way to go in Java, it is much nicer to stay type safe and use the interface as the anchor.